# AngularJS Performance With A Huge Application

Tags: angularjs

My team is looking at Angular for building the frontend of a huge application. Unfortunately, one of the customer requirements calls for a huge number of popup windows (think jquery-ui dialog windows... about 150 of them). It looks like I would have to wrap jquery-ui's dialog into a directive.

These popup windows can have multi-tab forms, data grid controls, etc that are populated via ajax calls.

I've seen references to performance issues if more than a certain amount of information is added to the scope. So, given my limitations, is Angular really a good choice for this project?

Comment: Are all of these 150 popup windows going to be in the DOM at once? Or are they spread across multiple pages?  Each page/partial/directive in Angular has its own scope.  And scopes are created and destroyed as needed.  So unless all the dialogs are being created at once, you should be fine...

Comment: I appreciate the answer. I've worked through the tutorial but was waiting to see if it was worth working on the more advanced stuff.